# How can I pass multiple table types to a single method?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unit-of-work

In our Model Context there are many tables of the type `IDbSet<TEntity>`.
How can I write a method that will accept multiple types of these tables as a parameter?

Edit: I only need to accept one parameter, but it could be any type of table from the Context.

Edit: Ok so I'm trying to use the method posted by Praveen:

```
void Method<TEntity>(IDbSet<TEntity> set) where TEntity : class
{
    //method code goes here
}
```

But I'm getting an issue when I try to call the method: Intellisense says "constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations". Here is how I'm trying to call the method:

```
Table tableType = new Table(); 
Method(tableType);
```

Comment: What stops you from writing multiple parameters in your method? method(IDBSet<Entity> a, IDBSet<Entity> b)?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a function that allows a variable number of parameters with the `IDbSet<TEntity>` type?

Comment: TEntity is not recognized by Intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass TEntity in your method parameter you should do this.

```
void Method<TEntity>(IDbSet<TEntity> set) where TEntity : class
{
    //method code goes here
}
```

You can now call this method with any DbSet. E.g.

```
TestEntities testEntities = new TestEntities();
Method(testEntities.Tables);
```

However if you are looking to directly pass the Table and not the DbSet, you change the definition to

```
void Method<TEntity>(TEntity set) where TEntity : class
{
    //method code goes here
}
```

and call it like this

```
Method(new Table());
```

Comment: Actually I only need to pass one parameter, but it could be any table from the Model Context. When I use `public void Method(IDbSet<TEntity> table)` TEntity is not recognized by Intellisense.

Comment: using this gives the Intellisense error "constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations".

Comment: Are your sure you have copied it correctly. I just pasted this definition in my VS 2012 and it builds correctly.

Comment: Yes you're right I copied wrong. It now compiles.However I'm getting an error when I try to call the method. It says "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage". `Table tableType = new Table(); Method(tableType);`

Comment: What is this class Table? Is it your own class?

Comment: No its from the auto generated Model Context

Comment: Updated the answer as per your class Table. Please check.

Comment: Tried your new code but I still have the same error: "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage"

Comment: Have you removed the IDBset?

Comment: Okay I removed IDBSet and it now builds. However I having trouble using the tableType. Usually I access Context tables using Linq. E.g., `_entities.TableName.Where(x => x.Id = id);` Is there a way to use the `tableType` parameter in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a Base class or an interface, and add a Generics Constrians to your method. like:
public vlid Method (IDbSet list) where TEntity : IYourInterface

then you will get intellisense in the method.